# can we mix MTU values in cluster

Tags: linux, networking, hadoop, mtu, jumboframes

- we have hadoop cluster ( all machines are linux redhat machines version 7.x  )
- on the VM machines we set `MTU=8900` and all other machines we set `MTU=9000`
- we set on VM `MTU=8900` because we saw some network problems with `MTU=9000`

My question:

dose mix of `MTU=9000` and `MTU=8900` is a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

All recent OS versions use Path MTU Discovery (PMTUD) so I think you should be fine.

On the other hand, the general recommendation is to set the same MTU to eliminate one potential problem. What makes you avoid using 8900 bytes on the other machines?

Answer (score 1):

You could end up with frame errors/drops if you mismatch mtu. It will also cause problems for some network protocols like ospf and mpls. Have you tried putting 9000 (or perhaps 9216) everywhere but instead adjust the mss?